# Type Error while downloading 'http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.7.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd'

Tags: gwt, vaadin, vaadin7

I try to compile my widgetset in Vaadin 7.7.26 but I get an error :

```
Unable to find 'AppDefaultWidgetset.gwt.xml' on your classpath
```

but the name is correct and the file is there.

Opening the .gwt.xml file I see the following error :

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Error while downloading 'http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.7.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd' to C:\Users\axioma28\.lemminx\cache\http\google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com\svn\tags\2.7.0\distro-source\core\src\gwt-module.dtd.    AppDefaultWidgetset.gwt.xml /pax-ui-vaadin-client/src/main/resources    line 6  Language Servers
```

Update the wigetset does nothing.

Tks

Answer (score 2):

The error about downloading the dtd shouldn't be related to the compilation problem. The dtd is used by the IDE to provide better validation and content suggestions when editing the file, but it shouldn't have any direct impact on compilation.

I'm thus strongly suspecting that the problem is about where the file is located in combination with how the compiler is launched. Since you don't provide any information on those aspects, I cannot even speculate on what to look for

Answer (score 2):

Your `AppDefaultWidgetset.gwt.xml` should by default be located in `src\main\resources\whatever\your\package\name\is\` and your widgetset configuration should similarly have e.g. in `@VaadinServletConfiguration` annotation for your Servlet something like `widgetset = "whatever.your.package.name.is.AppDefaultWidgetset"` -- is this where your file is and how you refer to it, and if not, does changing it to be like this help?

(And if you have custom client-side classes, those should be in `src\main\java\whatever\your\package\name\is\client\` for them to be found.)

Also, if you want to use newer Vaadin 7 versions than 7.7.17, make sure you have [extended support for Vaadin 7](https://vaadin.com/support/vaadin-7-extended-maintenance).

Edit: alternative options where the widgetset might be configured:

- annotation on your UI class:
  `@Widgetset("whatever.your.package.name.is.AppDefaultWidgetset")`
- web.xml:

```
        <init-param>
                <description>Application widgetset</description>
                <param-name>widgetset</param-name>
                <param-value>whatever.your.package.name.is.AppDefaultWidgetset</param-value>
        </init-param>
```